# Opening youtube video within the application - Phonegap application

Tags: youtube, hybrid

I am developing a hybrid application which supports android and iOS.
I need to embed the youtube video in the application such that it should be opened within the application.

I have tried using iFrame and it is working on the browser.
But in the iPhone the youtube video which is embedded in the iframe is opening in the external browser and not withing the application.
Searching on google, I found that in the cordova plist (cordova iOS application) there is option to allow allexternalURL's to be opened within the webview. But, this is impacting other places where few url's should be opened in the external browsers and not within the application.

Please suggest if there is any way to integrate the youtube where the video should be opened within the application for hybrid app.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice [**Tutorial**](http://eisabainyo.net/weblog/2012/01/24/embed-a-youtube-video-iframe-in-phonegap-app/)

codes For a quick Access.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>YouTube video</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <script src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9HDeEbJyNK8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    </body>
</html>


          *.youtube.com
          *.ytimg.com
```

Video will play on your Simulator Also.

Comment: Thanks Suhas. But as I mentioned in the question itself I have tried this solution of changing the plist option. With this solution it will open all the external hosts within the application. This is impacting the other feature where some url's should be opened in the external browser.